# Date Time Picker - Minutes picker modal not shown

Tags: datepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

Modal for hours works when I click on the number that represents hours. However, when I click on the number that represents minutes, the modal is not shown.

[Data Picker Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMUs5.png)

What could be happening, any idea?

I have tried Jquery versions and datapickers versions files for Bootstrap 3 (Datepicker v4). I haven't tried the Tempus Dominus Date/Time Picker v6. I would like to make Datepicker v4 to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.